# Passing data backwards by clicking a UITableView cell - iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, segue

My application has 3 UIViewControllers. [image: horrible paint] ViewController #1-->#2 is by "show segue" and from #2-->#3 is by "present modally". #3 has a UITableView. When a cell is clicked, I would like to jump back to #1 and pass data from #3 as well. 
I managed to dismiss #3 and go back to #2 by using this function, but this is not what I need. Please advise.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                     self.funcToCall(id: id)
}
```

Comment: The usual (easy) way is using segues and unwind segue. A segue can also be presented modally.

Comment: I know, @vadian. I have trouble combining it with the table view.

Comment: Create a delegate

Answer (score 3):

you have to use delegate to pass the value to vc#1 and pop to root view controller.

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep. I'm a new developer, sorry for the question:  between VC3 and VC1 there are two segues: present modally and show. Can I still use  pop to root view controller?

Comment: if you dont required "show" and "present modally" for specific purpose, then why dont you simply use Push. Its a best practice.

Comment: As far as I understand, in Swift 3 show and push is the same (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just learning this). I'm using also present modally because it makes sense in my app. Also for practicing..

Comment: your kind help please :)  @Pradeep Kashyap

Comment: I now use 2 "show" segues. I'm using delegate to pass data. I performs the next steps: 1. I create a file with a Delegate protocol: protocol Delegate { func doSomething(with data: Data) } Then in vc3: class DestinationViewController: UIViewController { var delegate: Delegate? func passDataBackwards() { let data = Data() delegate?.doSomething(with: data) } } And in vc1: class SourceViewController: UIViewController, Delegate { func doSomething(with data: Data) { // Uses the data passed back } but var delegate is nil, so it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: {  if let navController = self.navigationController, navController.viewControllers.count >= 2 {
            let viewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! VC1
            delegateDemo = viewController
            delegateDemo?.toMakeSomething()
        }
        
       _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
} use this one its woking fine on did select of row in table view

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the desired result by defining another segue that triggers on tapping the UITableViewCell. Make sure to assign it an identifier. Add the code below to the UITableView controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Segue Identifier Here" {
    var dest = segue.destinationViewController as! DestViewController
    dest.dataObj = dataToBePassed
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure adding another segue is the proper way to do that (although I'm very new to iOS dev)...

Answer (score 0):

Try pass data through `NSNotificationCenter`

**Register to receive notification in VC1's ViewDidLoad**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myData(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil)

     // handle notification
     func myData(_ notification: NSNotification) {
          let object = notification.object // You data
     }
```

**Post this notification in VC3**

```
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: **yourData**) 

   // Do popToRootViewContoller
```

Comment: Thanks, KKRocks. Regarding the comment "// Do popToRootViewContoller": between VC3 to VC1 there are two segues: present modally and show segue.

Comment: then dismiss that controller answer is independent to naviagtion any operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures, here is an example:

### ViewController3

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    var cellSelectedHandler: ((String)->Void)?
    .
    .
    .

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cellSelectedHandler != nil {
        cellSelectedHandler!("data you want to pass")
    }
 }
```

### ViewController2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    //add vc3 as instance variable
    let vc3 =  ViewController3()
```

### ViewController1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func presentViewController2() {
        let vc2 = ViewController2()
        vc2.vc3.cellSelectedHandler = {(dataPassed) in
            vc2.vc3.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            _ = vc2.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

            //use dataPassed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, janusbalatbat. I think I'm missing something: when is cellSelectedHandler !=nil? When I'm in vc3 and I click a cell, it's always nil.